# Change title of UINavigationBar created by Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, title

All is in the title. I want to change the title of my UINavigationBar that I created with Interface Builder ( Navigation Bar + Navigation Item ) in the "awakeFromNib" methode of my view class. But I don't know how to create the link with Interface Builder.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply write this when you're view is loaded:

self.navigationItem.title = @"Your title";

Should work fine :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: NB can only used with UINavigationBar associated with a view controller. From the docs ": This is a unique instance of UINavigationItem created to represent the view controller when it is pushed onto a navigation bar. The first time you access this property, the UINavigationItem is created. Therefore, you shouldn’t access this property if you are not using a navigation controller"